# TFS Branching needs an intermediate folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, version-control

We are trying to create a branch for `May` stable release in TFS but it always proposes me a branch under `$product/Release`, should I add a folder to get the hierarchy structure in the picture below? Why?

Our version control structure:

[image]

TFS create Branch dialog:

[image]

**EDIT:**

What if the hierarchy structure would be like this instead? Actually, we need to branch `May` from `2021` and `Sep` from `May`.

[image]

Comment: From your second picture it seems that tfs proposes the new branch to be under `$/Product/Release/`

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: You are right, I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you like, TFS just proposes the solution that makes more sense.

I am assuming here that 2021 is indeed a branch. So imagine the following:

1. The month is the December 2021 and you have 12 branches under the 2021 branch
2. I am a developer that needs to check out the 2021 to check some stuff there

Now I need to download 12 branches just to checkout 2021 branch.

Folders and branches are here for a reason.

- Use folders to indicate a collection of branches. 2021 would be a fine folder name
- Use the same naming convention for branches. Your first branch should be named January under the 2021 folder.

Then the TFS suggestion would make much more sense.

Comment: Thanks! So you recommend converting 2021 branch to a folder? What happens to the code and changesets we currently have under 2021 branch?

Comment: Rename the 2021 branch to January, create a folder 2021 under the releases forlder and add January in it. Then take the May branch from January and you are done!

Comment: Thanks for the solution provided @Athanasios, trying to apply it we figured out another challenge: we need to branch `May` from `2021` and `Sep` from `May`. How can we do it?

Comment: Once you have created `May` just right click on `May` select `Branching and Merging` and `Branch`